# Navigation bar display with UIImage and UILabel for title

Tags: swift, uiimage, uilabel, navigationbar

I want to put navigation bar title with UIImage and UILabel.

```swift
let image = UIImage(systemName: "flame")
imageView.tintColor = R.color.fire()
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
self.navigationItem.title = "표시한 제품"
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: R.color.myPageMenu]
```

This is my code, but this code only shows `UIImage(systemName: "flame")`.

Comment: Where does a guy named 'imageView' come from?  Show the lines where you define and set it up.

Comment: Use a custom `UIView` with your `UIImageView` and `UILabel` laid out on it, then assign an instance of it to `titleView`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let image = UIImage(systemName: "flame")
let title = "표시한 제품"

let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.image = image

let textLabel = UILabel()
textLabel.text  = text
textLabel.textAlignment = .center

//Stack View
let stackView   = UIStackView()
stackView.axis  = NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.horizontal
stackView.distribution  = UIStackView.Distribution.equalSpacing
stackView.alignment = UIStackView.Alignment.center
stackView.spacing   = 4.0

stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(textLabel)

self.navigationItem.titleView = stackView
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can add `UIImageView` and `UILabel` in the Navigation bar.

File: ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var navView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var navTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var navImage: UIImageView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setNavTitleView()
    }

    func setNavTitleView() {
        navTitle.text = "표시한 제품"
        navTitle.textColor = .lightGray
        navImage.image = UIImage(systemName: "flame")
        navImage.tintColor = .red
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .lightGray
        navigationItem.titleView = navView
    }

}
```

Storyboard:

[image]

Output:

[image]